# Match users to their preferences by ID

Tags: java, object-oriented

I am using Java, but coming from a JavaScript background. I have two objects:

1. a list of users
2. an Iterable of users preferences

I am joining them into a new users object that I call `newUser`, and then adding `newUser` to a List of `User` and returning that.

I need to match up users to their user preferences based on a shared id.  If I was using JS I would get the id of the user and filter the user preferences based on the same id.  I wasn't able to figure that out, so I used a for loop for users and then a foreach loop for users preferences and the used an if statement to find a match.

```
var users = service.getUsers();
List<User> value = new ArrayList<User>();
var usersPreferences = _userRepo.findAll();
for(int i =0; i < users.size(); i++){
    var user = users.get(i);
    boolean[] isFound = {false};
    usersPreferences.forEach(prefUser -> {
        if(prefUser.getId() == user.getId()){
            User newUser = new User(user, prefUser);
            value.add(newUser);
            isFound[0] = true;
        }
    });
    if(!isFound[0]){
        User newUser = new User(user);
            value.add(newUser);
    }
}
return value;
```

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/java-8-streams-filter-map-reduce/

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```java
        var users = service.getUsers();
        List<User> value = new ArrayList<User>();
        var usersPreferences = _userRepo.findAll();
```

Personally, I dislike `var` with a passion because of exactly *such* usage. I can't see half-the types, so I have to make a few assumptions here.

---

```java
for(int i =0; i < users.size(); i++){
```

First, I'm against using single-letter variable names, with the only exception being dimensions. Having said that, you can most likely use a for-each loop here (I'm not seeing the type of `users`, but I assume that it is a `List`).

```java
for (User user : users) {
```

---

```java
List<User> value = new ArrayList<User>();
```

This variable name could be better, because it doesn't make much sense.

---

```java
            boolean[] isFound = {false};
            usersPreferences.forEach(prefUser -> {
                if(prefUser.getId() == user.getId()){
                    User newUser = new User(user, prefUser);
                    value.add(newUser);
                    isFound[0] = true;
                }
            });
            if(!isFound[0]){
                User newUser = new User(user);
                    value.add(newUser);
            }
```

Instead of using a lambda, you could use a simple for-each loop:

```java
            boolean isFound = false;
            for (UserPreference userPreference : userPreferences) {
                if(prefUser.getId() == user.getId()){
                    User newUser = new User(user, prefUser);
                    value.add(newUser);
                    isFound = true;
                }
            }
            if(!isFound){
                User newUser = new User(user);
                value.add(newUser);
            }
```

Even better would be if you would extract the second loop into its own function, as that would reduce the complexity of your logic:

```java
private User createUserWithPreferences(User user, List<UserPreferences> userPreferences) {
    for (UserPreference userPreference : userPreferences) {
        if (userPreference.getUserId() == user.getId()) {
            return new User(user, userPreference);
        }
    }
    
    return new User(user);
}

List<User> createdUsers = new ArrayList<>();

for (User user : users) {
    createdUsers.add(createUserWithPreferences(user, userPreferences);
}
```